# Turning an array into array of objects but cannot run function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Alright, I must be missing something here.  I have an object:

```
export class Country {
    id: number = 0
    name: string = ''

    getNamePlusBob() {
        return this.name + 'bob'
    }

}
```

And I get the data from an API in an array, then pass it to the browser.

Once i have the data I want to turn the array into an array of objects of type 'Country'.

So I made this function (not sure if Hydrate is the correct term here?):

```
function hydrateArray(data, entity) {
    let returnArray = []
    console.log(data)
    data.forEach((row) => {
        const object = entity;
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
            if(Object.hasOwn(object, key)) {
                object[key] = value
            } else {
                console.log('Key not found in entity', key)
            }
        }
        console.log(object.getNamePlusBob())
        returnArray.push({...object})
    })
    return returnArray
}

const countries = hydrateArray(countryData, new Country())
```

In the console.log in the function, I can run the getNamePlusBob() and it returns the name plus bob.  However, on the returned array `countries`, I cannot:

`console.log(countries[0].getNamePlusBob())`

`TypeError: countries[0].getNamePlusBob is not a function`

Why not? It was inside the `hydrateArray` function, why cant I run it outside?

Comment: `getNamePlusBob` is not an own-property on the object created by doing `new Country()` (ie: `entity`), it is a property on its prototype, and properties/methods on the prototype aren't copied when using the spread syntax `...`. You should be calling `new Country()` within your  `hydrateArray` array if you want to create new country instances.

Comment: how do I do that, as I want the function be able to perform the task with any object I give it?

Comment: If you want it to be generic, then you can keep the code as it currently is, but use `Object.create()` to define `object` within your object to keep the prototype from `entity`.

Comment: @NickParsons so instead of `object = entity` I have replaced it with `const object = Object.create(entity)` and I still cannot run the plusBob function on the returned array.

Comment: You should only be pushing object now, you don’t need to spread anymore as Object.create will make a unique object for you

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you for help, I really appreciatte it but it is stil failing.  Using Object.Create, and `returnArrray.push(object)`, The function now works but there is no data.  In the console it is writing `Key not found in entity`.  None of the keys are able to be found in the object when using `Object.create()`

Comment: oh yes, you'll also need to ensure that you change the condition for `Object.hasOwn(object, key)` as `object` is now a new object with no own-properties, you'll want to do `Object.hasOwnn(entity, key)`

Comment: @NickParsons yes that works great now! Thank you, we got there in the end.  Do you want to put it as an answer? Otherwise i'll add the final code here.

Comment: That’s great, as this was closed as a duplicate, I can’t add an answer (most of what I’ve mentioned is covered in the links above your question).